# Configure Up/Down arrow to move up/down a row in html table

Tags: html, html-table

I have an html table, pressing TAB moves to next element in row and SHIFT-TAB goes back one element, this is fine hence I dont want to modify *tabindex* attribute to change this.

But I would also like the user to be able to traverse the table up and down using the arrows keys, how do I implement this.

Im using Html5 with a little bit of Javascript and CSS

```
<table class="edittable">
<tr>
  <th class="tableheading verysmallinputfield" style="position:relative">
      <label>
          #
      </label>
  </th>
  <th class="tableheading smallinputfield" style="position:relative">
      <label>
          Disc No
      </label>
  </th>
  <th class="tableheading smallinputfield" style="position:relative">
      <label>
          Disc Total
      </label>
  </th>
  <th class="tableheading largeinputfield" style="position:relative">
      <label>
          Disc Subtitle
      </label>
  </th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="tableheading">
      1
  </td>
  <td>
      <input name="1DISC_NO" value="01" style="width:100%" type="number" min="1" max="999">
  </td>
  <td>
      <input name="1DISC_TOTAL" value="01" style="width:100%" type="number" min="1" max="999">
  </td>
  <td>
      <input name="1DISC_SUBTITLE" value="" style="width:100%" type="text">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="tableheading">
      2
  </td>
  <td>
      <input name="2DISC_NO" value="01" style="width:100%" type="number" min="1" max="999">
  </td>
  <td>
      <input name="2DISC_TOTAL" value="01" style="width:100%" type="number" min="1" max="999">
  </td>
  <td>
      <input name="2DISC_SUBTITLE" value="" style="width:100%" type="text">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Update**

I am getting key press detected, but having problem with activeElement. The element is defined but when I try to get tagname or parent its always undefined, dont understand why.

```
<script>
            document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    switch (e.key) {
        case 'ArrowUp':
            var el = document.activeElement;
            alert($(el)); 
            alert($(el).tagName); 
            alert($(el).closest('td').innerHtml); 
            break;
        case 'ArrowDown':
            var el = document.activeElement;
            alert($(el).closest('td').innerHtml); 
            break;
    }
};
        </script>
```

Comment: can you provide some code? some examples? it is not very clear what do you mean by moving up/down a row in a table. Is it supposed to be highlighting the current row? Is it suppose to change the background of it? Please be more detailed. Thanks!

Comment: @N.Ivanov  No just change the focus, e.g user is currently in tr1, td3, if he presses down button should now be in tr2, td3. What I didnt make clear is each td contains an input field.

Comment: it would be doable with jQuery. I assume you put event handlers for arrow presses, and then based on whatever is on focus, you move based on the desired direction. E.g if you are on row1 col3, and want to go to row2 col3, in jQuery you would get the next <tr> and then the appropriate <td> and just set focus to that. I hope this helps!

Comment: okay I will have a go at that, thanks

Comment: @N.Ivanov I have had a go, but having problem with the activeElement

Comment: sorry, I can't help as I haven't done much of vanilla js, I have mostly worked with jQuery

Comment: @N.Ivanov as that has helped, just relaized have usual el element but then refer to it as if JQuery element so so I need to use jquery to get activeElement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now have it working

**Html**:

```
   <table class="edittable" id="menu_disctable">
      <tr>
        <th class="tableheading verysmallinputfield" style="position:relative">
          <label>
                                            #
                                        </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading smallinputfield" style="position:relative">
          <label>
                                            Disc No
                                        </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading smallinputfield" style="position:relative">
          <label>
                                            Disc Total
                                        </label>
        </th>
        <th class="tableheading largeinputfield" style="position:relative">
          <label>
                                            Disc Subtitle
                                        </label>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="menu_disc1">
        <td class="tableheading">
          1
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="1_DISC_NO" id="1_DISC_NO" value="01" style="width:100%" type="number" min="1" max="999">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="1_DISC_TOTAL" id="1_DISC_TOTAL" value="01" style="width:100%" type="number" min="1" max="999">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="1_DISC_SUBTITLE" id="1_DISC_SUBTITLE" value="" style="width:100%" type="text">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="menu_disc2">
        <td class="tableheading">
          2
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="2_DISC_NO" id="2_DISC_NO" value="01" style="width:100%" type="number" min="1" max="999">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="2_DISC_TOTAL" id="2_DISC_TOTAL" value="01" style="width:100%" type="number" min="1" max="999">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="2_DISC_SUBTITLE" id="2_DISC_SUBTITLE" value="" style="width:100%" type="text">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

**Javascript**

```
document.onkeydown =
  function updownintable(e) {
    switch (e.key) {
      case 'ArrowUp':
        var el = document.activeElement;
        var rowNo = el.id.substring(0, el.id.indexOf("_"));
        var fieldId = el.id.substring(el.id.indexOf("_"));
        if (rowNo > 1) {
          rowNo--;
          var newId = rowNo + fieldId;
          var newEl = document.getElementById(newId);
          if (newEl != null) {
            newEl.focus();
          }
        }
        break;
      case 'ArrowDown':
        var el = document.activeElement;
        var rowNo = el.id.substring(0, el.id.indexOf("_"));
        var fieldId = el.id.substring(el.id.indexOf("_"));
        rowNo++
        var newId = rowNo + fieldId;
        var newEl = document.getElementById(newId);
        if (newEl != null) {
          newEl.focus();
        }
        break;
    }
  };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/paultaylor/480Ln4y6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Solution, where I've tried to keep JS simple?

```
document.onkeydown =
  function updownintable(e) {
    var el = document.activeElement;
    var rowNo = el.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    var columnNo = el.parentNode.cellIndex;
    var bodyElement = document.getElementById(tableElementId).children[0];

    switch (e.key) {
      case 'ArrowUp':
        rowNo--;
        break;
      case 'ArrowDown':
        rowNo++;
        break;
      case 'ArrowLeft':
        columnNo--;
        break;
      case 'ArrowRight':
        columnNo++;
        break;
    }
    bodyElement.children[rowNo].children[columnNo].children[0].focus();
};
```

Where tableElementId = id of html table.